# why C not support TDD. It can't mock function?

Tags: c, unit-testing, alias, cmocka

## target : mock (main.c) without modified any original file (work.a)

objcopy work.a --add-symbol _real_test1=.text:00000000000126ed,weak  --weaken work.a

00000000000126ed is test1 address by command (nm work.a)

override function and call real function in main.c without original file

## it can work

#work.a

```
void test1(){
   printf("old");
}
void test2(){
   test1();
}
```

#main.c

```
int real_flag=0;
void test1(){
   if(real_flag){
     _real_test1();
   }else{
     printf("new");
   }
}

int main(){
   test2();//print new
   real_flag=1;
   test2();//print old
}
```

## question : how can I make mutiple real_function

ex: test1,__real_test1
test2,__real_test2...

or other method to mock function

## fail to try

fail to try: becuse it need modify original file work.a

```
void _real_test1() __attribute__((alias("test1")));
```

fail to try: becuse it just modify function name but not mock function

```
objcopy --redefine-syms
```

fail to try: becuse it just work in main.c,it still call old test1 in work.a

```
gcc -Wl,--wrap=test1
```

Comment: Your question is excellent, it's my fault I don't understand it at all.

Answer (score 0):

## create mock function override test1 function

1. command objcopy to make functions of static library weaken
2. override test1 function in testing program

## load real function by shared library

3. make shared library libfunc.so
4. dlsym load test1 by function pointer from libfunc.so
   you can call test1 and __real_test1